# Selenium : ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x0000011B792D8660>, but it must be an int, float or None. (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

I Dont why but the chrome driver dosent open, it give me error :
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x0000011B792D8660>, but it must be an int, float or None.

this is the Code :

```py
# Path to the Chrome WebDriver 
path = #path

# Create a Chrome WebDriver service
chrome_service = Service(path)


# Create a Chrome WebDriver instance with the desired capabilities
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)

# Navigate to a webpage
driver.get("https://linkedin.com/uas/login")


# waiting for the page to load
time.sleep(2)

# entering username
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")

# Enter Email 
username.send_keys(#email)

# entering password
pword = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")

# Enter Password
pword.send_keys(#password)

# Clicking on the log in button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

i did try pip install selenium==4.9.0

Answer (score 3):

I'm use selenium==3.141.0 and also got this error.

After downgrade the urllib3 from v2 to v1.26.18, the error fixed.